# TransactionFlowAttribute attribute set to Mandatory but the channel's binding is not configured with a TransactionFlowBindingElement

Tags: wcf, distributed-transactions

I have a big problem. I am trying to create a web service that will work with a distributed transaction.
All the code below is on the server side of the web service(the web service that is called from a client).
I wrote this in my interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IClientOperations
{

    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(TriggerExecInput))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(TriggerExecOutput))]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
    TriggerExecOutput TriggeredProfileDataUpdate(TriggerExecInput triggerInputData, bool isST3StatusActive);
```

And this in the web.config file:

```
<services>
  <service name="ClientOperationsService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_Common" contract="SL.STAdmin.Applications.WebAPI.IClientOperations"/>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding_Common" transactionFlow="true">
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

If I right click the .svc file and click on "View in browser" I get the following error

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: At least one operation on the 'ClientOperations' contract is configured with the TransactionFlowAttribute attribute set to Mandatory but the channel's binding 'BasicHttpBinding' is not configured with a TransactionFlowBindingElement. The TransactionFlowAttribute attribute set to Mandatory cannot be used without a TransactionFlowBindingElement.
```

I have other .svc files that don't use transactions.
They all work well.
I don't understand why it still tries to use the BasicHttpTransaction when I instruct it to use the other binding type.

DOes anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `BasicHttpTransaction` is not a binding, I think you mean `BasicHttpBinding`

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your `<system.serviceModel>` element of your web.config:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_Common"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few things to get the transaction working.
Add the transactionflow to your operation

```
[OperationContract]
[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
void TransactionSupported(int id, string name);
```

After that you add an operationbehavior to your implementation

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
public void TransactionSupported(int id, string name)
{
    ...
}
```

In your config file you need to add the transaction flow to your host binding

```
<system.serviceModel>
    ...
    <bindings>
      <netNamedPipeBinding> --> Your binding (don't use basicHttpBinding)
        <binding transactionFlow="true"/>
      </netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And last but not least you need to set the transactionflow of your client to get it working. In my example I do this in my code in my unit test, I think you can also do this in your configuration of your client, in your config file.

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(callback,
              new NetNamedPipeBinding() { TransactionFlow = true },
              new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/ping"));
```